# Name for the stick running through the small and narrow leaf of a big coconut leaf

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there any specific term in English for the stick running through the small and narrow leaf of a big coconut leaf?

> In coconut tree, there is a stick(resembling a spinal cord) running through the small and narrow leaf of its main big leaf. In my mother tongue Malayalam, we call it "eerkili". I have encountered several occasions where I had to reluctantly use the Malayalam word for this while communicating in English.

Comment: Spine? What is a small and narrow leaf of a big main leaf? Picture?

Comment: Do you mean the part that runs through the individual leaflet, you can pull it out and use it for a toothpick or use it to stitch things together?

Comment: @Frank Absolutely! That long and narrow stick!

Comment: They call it a _coconut leaf stick_ on the web

Comment: @mplungjan I actually wanted the colloquial word for that.

Comment: Off-topic comment probably, but I just couldn't stop myself expressing how I like this "tropical" question. (:

Comment: The more I think about it, the more likely it seems that you would be able to use _stem_. I think most people are aware that a coconut leaf is usually called a _frond_ (like a branch) and the frond carries what would be be easily recognised as _leaves_ (the leaflets). To say _the stem of a coconut leaf_ is probably as understandable as you'll get for an English speaker who is not overly familiar with the uses of parts of the coconut nor botanical terms. You'll probably still have to explain it's properties though.

Comment: Note that most of these answers are technical. 'midrib' is understandable; one can figure out that it must mean, but out of context most people wouldn't know that. 'rachis' is very technical and few would even recognize it as an English word.

Comment: There are no colloquial words in English for the parts of a palm frond. As noted by several answers, "mid-rib" would come closest. The botanical names exist, of course. But the specialized traditional usages of palm frond parts does not exist in major English speaking countries. In instances where such usage occurs, e.g. India, I would think the regional language name would be borrowed, if "that little rib section down the middle of the frond leaflet" was not sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

The "spine" of both the leaf and each pinna of the leaf appears to be called the ***midrib***.

[image: Detail of coconut leaf] [Adityamadhav83 via [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_coconut_palm_leaf_at_Madhurawada.JPG)]

> *Cocos nucifera* is a large palm, growing up to 30 m (98 ft) tall, with pinnate leaves 4–6 m (13–20 ft) long, and pinnae 60–90 cm long
>
> [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut_tree)]

> Pinnately veined leaves have one large central vein, called the ***midrib,*** which extends from the base of the blade to its tip.
>
> [[Robinson Library](http://www.robinsonlibrary.com/science/botany/anatomy/leafparts.htm)]

> **midrib**
>   A large strengthened vein along the midline of a leaf.
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/midrib)]

Comment: +1 but it's questionable if many English speakers would identify 'coconut leaflet midrib' as the flexible stick you can pull from a coconut leaflet. I imagine that would be mostly due to a lack of awareness that there is such a thing. I wonder if there is a more colloquial term (in English) probably from the 18th or 19th century.

Comment: Could you provide me with a colloquial term for the midrib of the inner leaflets?

Comment: I'd use *midrib*. It specifies a rib down the middle of something. It's far more colloquial than *rachis*. Pinnate leaves have a midrib in each blade and what would probably be called a *central stalk* supporting the separate pinnae.

Comment: Midrib is also used in [this in.com article](http://ibnlive.in.com/news/its-a-fair-game/181389-60-123.html) _ Incredibly, pickles made out of bamboo’ and ‘eerkili’ (mid-rib of a coconut leaf) have been brought out, and have found enough takers._

Comment: In botanical terms, the midrib is called a costa. see 3rd paragraph at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frond. In OED as the botanical term for midrib with costæ as the plural. (almost no-one will know that)

Comment: I'm still completely unclear what ANYONE is referring to! Heh!  There one image so far but it contains at least 3 or 4 possibilities as to what is meant!

Comment: @Frank " I wonder if there is a more colloquial term (in English) probably from the 18th or 19th century." - I sincerely doubt it. The Seminoles were around and likely used such materials - and would thus have had names for the parts. But the usage of such simple native materials and methods was typically scorned by the majority populations. So probably no colloquial names in English.

Answer (score 4):

***Leaflet midrib***

[from uoregon.edu](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~mspp/kapingamarangi/Kpg-c.htm)

[image]

Figure 10.-Coconut tree and its parts.

a, tree: 1, trunk (rakau); 2, base of trunk (tona); 3, roots (aka); 4, leaf (rou niu); 5, center keaves (tira).

b, leaf parts: 1, **midrib** (takai niu); 2, leaflet (mata rou niu); 3, **leaflet midrib** (tuaniu).

c, flower parts: 1,whole flower (karoro); 2, flower sheath (taume); 3, stalk of nut (pa karihi); 4, stalk of bunch (kauroro).

d, mature fruit: 1, outer skin (kiri taha); 2, husk (puru); 3, shell (ipu); 4, flesh (kaniu); 5, fluid (nia wai, plural); 6, nut stalk (pa karihi);.

e, growing nut (homo): 1, roots (aka); 2, leaf stipule (kaka); 3, leaf (rou homo); 4, central leaf (tira homo); 5, spongy interior (upu).

---

***Older finds***

I found this image at [bioversityinternational.org](http://www.bioversityinternational.org/fileadmin/bioversity/publications/Web_version/108/ch14.htm):

[image]

but this one calls your specific part a midrib (rachis):

[image]

Comment: What do we call the spine of leaflets that arise from the rachis?

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. So, is the spine of leaflets(pinnae) called as midrib?

Comment: Leaflet midrib. See update

Comment: So this is now the same as my answer?

Comment: I guess so - from a different angle - so should I delete mine after all this investigation?

Comment: by far the best answer

Comment: @mplungjan By no means should you delete a correct answer which is not absolutely identical in all ways to (or a strict subset of) another answer.

Comment: Well someone thought it should be voted down

Comment: Is "keaves" a misspelling?

Comment: Possibly - not by me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the term used in botany is  *rachis*:

> - In plants, a rachis is the main axis of a compound structure. It can be the main stem of a compound leaf, such as in Acacia or ferns, or the main, flower-bearing portion of an inflorescence above a supporting peduncle.

Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachis#In_botany

> - Pinnately Compound (Pinnate): With A Rachis

Source: http://waynesword.palomar.edu/termlf1.htm

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leaf%20rachis%2Cleaf%20midrib&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleaf%20rachis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleaf%20midrib%3B%2Cc0): leaf rachis vs leaf midrib.

Comment: What do we call the spine of leaflets that arise from the rachis?

Comment: Have a look at the second link I have attached.

Answer (score 1):

midrib (petiole) of leaflet

The whole leaf is called coconut fond.
stalk (petiole) of frond = Midrib.
then leaflet of a frond.
midrib (petiole) of leaflet
https://www.flickr.com/photos/joegoauk73/16202081480/
the above / below pic is a broom entirely made of midribs